# How can I retrieve ACF google map data and use my own custom fields and map instead?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

My question is whether there is a plugin capable of recovering all the coordinates, latitude and longitude generated by the google map custom field from ACF for each wordpress post ?

I would like to automatically inject them into two default custom fields (want to avoid doing it manually if possible). My goal is to permanently stop using the google map API.

I'm using mapbox for all my maps, but to get the lat lng data from all post I'm still using the ACF google map custom field. Thank you if someone could answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do this with a plugin and not with some custom code, [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/) would probably help: You do an export of the posts and then you do an import which will update existing posts. During the import, you would instruct the plugin to fill in the new fields with the values from the old ones and leave the rest of the post's data intact.

But perhaps you could use a different approach all along: since your old google maps fields remain on your database, you could adjust your code to check if the new fields have values and if they don't, do a check for the old fields as a fallback. e.g.:

```
$gmaps_field = get_field('acf_google_maps_field');
$old_lat = $gmaps_field['lat'];
$old_lng = $gmaps_field['lng'];
$new_lat = get_field('new_lat');
$new_lng = get_field('new_lng');

$lat = $new_lat ? $new_lat : $old_lat;
$lng = $new_lng ? $new_lng : $old_lng;

if($lat && $lng) {
// Do something.
}
```

Comment: oh great, thank you very much, i'll look at this closer and come back here !!! thank you very much for your help!